# list alignment issue html

Tags: html, css

I have a list defined as

```
<ul id="one">
  <li>Long sentence of text</li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

The long sentence of text in the list messes the left alignment.

i tried

```
#one li{
   display: inline;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

But this removes the bullet points. How can I maintain the left alignment as well as retain the bullet points?

Comment: what do you want left aligned

Comment: ` display: inline;` should be removing your bullet points.

Comment: Run your code without ANY css, you will see the behaviour that you are after. Then it's just figuring out which css changes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u check it in browser.When i run your code w/o css i get the following result.
[image]

Comment: Yes, it causes problem in firefox. The long sentence continues to the next line where it comes below the dot. Hence the left alignment is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

The bullet is outside of the the list item, so when u do display: inline; it is getting cut off
Doing the following should fix this.

```
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default style of bullet points in all browsers is already what you require.  Therefore you must have something that changes this.  Are you using any libraries or reset.css files?  Just inspect the element (e.g. in Firebug) and look at what styles have been applied.